# Error in FETCH NEXT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fetch

I have a Razor code:

```
"SELECT * FROM Cat ORDER BY [NameCat] ASC OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY";
```

But it does not work.

The error is:

> The number of lines provided for the count parameter lines of the TOP
>   or FETCH clause must be an integer.

`FETCH` is an integer! 
`@0` and `@1` are integers.

Where am I wrong?

Complete code:

```
@{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        var recCount = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cat");
        var db = Database.Open(App.connDatabase);
        var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Cat ORDER BY [NameCat] ASC OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY";"
        var cat = db.Query(strQuery, Request["jtStartIndex"], Request["jtPageSize"]).ToList();

        var json = Json.Encode(new { Result = "OK", Records = cat, TotalRecordCount = recCount });
        Response.Write(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var json = Json.Encode(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        Response.Write(json);
    }
}
```

`jtStartIndex` and `jtPageSize` are int!

Comment: Nothing to do with `razor`. This is an `sql` question. How are you executing this query? Do you pass `int` type parameters to the server? Can you show your code...

Comment: `Request[]` returns `strings`, you need to cast/convert them into `int` type.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply Kaf...
but how can I?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters `Request["jtStartIndex"]` and `Request["jtPageSize"]` need to be parsed to `int` in order to pass them as `integer`. When you use them without parsing, they get passed as `strings`. Try it like this:

```
var cat = db.Query(strQuery, int.Parse(Request["jtStartIndex"]), int.Parse(Request["jtPageSize"]).ToList();
```